# Unit testing with moq and ms test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am new to this stuff and I read about test but I can't figure it out how to test this function :

```
   [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    [Route("user/byUsername/{username}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserByName(string username)
    {
        var user = await this.AppUserManager.FindByNameAsync(username);

        if (user != null)
        {
            return Ok(this.TheModelFactory.Create(user));
        }

        return NotFound();

    }
```

I want to use Moq and MS Test.Thank you.

Comment: What are you having trouble with in trying to test that method? As your question stands now, it is too broad. If we were to cover "how to test this function", then we would have to give a full tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have to paths in your method, so both can to be tested to have full coverage. Assumed the AppUserManager is injected into the class with di you are able to create a mock version of it that returns a null on the method FindByNameAsync(username), or a user. The Assert will test the NotFound and the returned Ok with content.

You would also be able to write a test to check if the attributes are present and have the correct content. That will guard you against typos and unexpected changes in the route or roles.